# Preview section stops updating if you start typing, choose to cancel leave this page and continue writing

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown-preview

I noticed this today - start posting a new answer or a new question. Now close the tab, you'll get a prompt whether to leave the page or stay on it. Choose to stay on the page, and resume writing, you'll see that preview section isn't updated anymore.

This seems to happen on Google Chrome ( v4.0.266.0) but not Firefox 3.5.6. 
In Opera I wasn't asked to confirm if I want to close the tab ( log as a separate bug ? )
[A look at the bug http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/2697/uploadr.jpg](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/2697/uploadr.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Opera I wasn't asked to confirm if I want to close the tab ( log as a separate bug ? )

Unfortunately, as much as I would desperately like to, we cannot log Opera as a bug.

Edit: I can't repro this in Chrome v3 (current release version).

1. start composing an answer (or a question, I tried both)
2. click the back button (I use my fourth mouse button which is auto-mapped to back)
3. decline the "leave page? yes / no" dialog that comes up (note that this dialog is provided by the browser, not us, so it does vary per browser)
4. I remain on the same page
5. I can still type and see the preview update

I noticed you are using **Chrome v4**. We do not support unreleased beta browsers.

Comment: About Chrome v4: Fair enough. 

About Opera: Is it because of the userbase of people who visit S[OFU] 
is low ?